kubuntu 24.04 LTS HDMI sounds do not work
Hall
I use Kubuntu 22.04 LTS in my lenovo T480s. All the things are ok when I connected the PHILIPS TV via HDMI.
Now I've made a fresh installation of kubuntu 24.04 LTS and no audio fron my tv connected via HDMI cable.
Apparently the TV is recognized. When I digit aplay -l in my terminal I can see:
**** Lista di PLAYBACK dispositivi hardware ****
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 0: ALC257 Analog [ALC257 Analog]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: HDMI 0 [PHILIPS FTV]
  Sottoperiferiche: 0/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0
scheda 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Sottoperiferiche: 1/1
  Sottoperiferica #0: subdevice #0

The system are using pipewire and it seams correctly up and running
● pipewire.socket - PipeWire Multimedia System Sockets
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.socket; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2024-12-23 11:10:55 CET; 17min ago
   Triggers: ● pipewire.service
     Listen: /run/user/1000/pipewire-0 (Stream)
             /run/user/1000/pipewire-0-manager (Stream)
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/pipewire.socket

dic 23 11:10:55 graffio-T480s systemd[2726]: Listening on pipewire.socket - PipeWire Multimedia System Sockets.

Any suggestions?
thanks in advance
graffio
